# Customize PagerTitleStrip in viewpager on android

Tags: android

i want customize pager title strip with some shapes like focused titlestrip below triangle shape without any library reference like viewpageindicator and so on.my view pager xml code below:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="800dp" >
        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#f06b29"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" /> 
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and i am excepted output like below figure(highlighted with red border):

[image]

i have searched google but,can't find solution! can any one help me how to do that?

Comment: Did you manage to do that?